# Comparing two linear models with anova() in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, anova

I don't quite understand what the p-value in this output means. I don't mean p-values as such, but in this case.

```
> Model 1: sl ~ le + ky 
> Model 2: sl ~ le   
  Res.Df     RSS Df   Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F) 
1     97 0.51113                              
2     98 0.51211 -1 -0.00097796 0.1856 0.6676
```

I get something like that, and now I am wondering which model is the better fit.
As there is only ONE and not TWO p-values I'm getting confused.
I get different pvalues using summary(model1) or summary(model2)

Now if

```
> fm2<-lm(Y~X+T)
```

(T being my indicator variable) and

```
> fm4<-lm(Y~X)
```

if I do

```
> anova(fm2,fm4)
```

this tests the null hypothesis `H0: alpha1==alpha2`
`(Ha: alpha1!=alpha2)`c(alpha being my intercept)
So it is tested whether it is better to have one intercept (=> `alpha1==alpha2`), or two intercepts (`alpha1!=alpha2`)

In this case we would now obviously reject the null Hypotheses, as the p-value is 0.6676.

This would mean we should rather stick with model `fm4`, as it is more appropriate for our data.

Did I draw the conclusions right? I tried my very best, but I am not sure what the p-value means. As there is only on, this is what I thought it might mean.
Can someone clear things up?

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean "would **not** obviously reject the null hypothesis" (rather than "now obviously reject")?  That would seem to make more sense given the rest of your question.

There is only one p-value because there are two models to compare, hence a single comparison (null hypothesis vs alternative, or really in this case null hypothesis vs unspecified alternative).  It sounds from what you have said above as though `le` is a continuous and `ky` is a categorical predictor, in which case you are comparing a model with a slope and an intercept against (as you said) a model with a single slope and two intercepts.  Because the p-value is relatively large, that means that the data do not provide evidence for an additive effect of `ky`.  The simpler model would generally be more appropriate (although be careful with this conclusion, as p-values are constructed to test hypotheses, not to choose among models).

The p-values you get for `summary()` of each individual model are the p-values for the effects of each of the parameters in each model, conditional on all the other parameters in that model. *If* your data are perfectly balanced (which is unlikely in a regression design), you should get the same answers from `summary` and `anova`, but otherwise the results from `anova` are generally preferable.

This question is probably more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com , as it is really about statistical interpretation rather than programming ...